# Webview with here-map in android x which supported by nokia x mobile

Tags: android-x86, here-api, nokiax

I want to open here map in web view using Eclipse in Nokia x which also support the android x.

Please help me or provide uri lancher for this

Thank u .

Answer (score 0):

I can see two separate questions in there, one for having HERE maps on Nokia X inside webview, and the other one for launching the HERE maps with Uri.

Anyway, incase you really want to embed the HERE maps in a way that you can sue it from HTML, then I actually would have an example ready. Got it done yesterday, and you can find it from [github](https://github.com/DrJukka/PhoneGap/tree/master/map)

Its based on MapKit plugin for Google maps v2, and i made it also to work with HERE when it is run inside Nokia X environment.

Feel free to work on teh project as you wish, or use the original plug-in, and then just use the [OneAPK porting guide](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/here-maps/one-apk-with-here-maps-and-google-maps.html), alongside the example for porting assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to launch HERE Drive from a webview. Any suggestions on what URI to use?

Comment: If I remember right the maps would be responding to the same strings as google maps would, but as far as I know there is no specific HERE things that would be available, at least there is no public information on the topic that I would be aware of.